# GUI areas restricted by the iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface, javafx, gluon

I would like to be able to use the areas that are occupied by the iOS in my app, using javaFX and Gluon. How can this be done?

That means any `javaFX controllers` functions as expected. Now they are almost impossible for a user to focus. When I have another controller in the middle area of the screen that one works like normal.

On iPhone 6 you can press the top most area and drag down to get access to a menu. The same exact thing with the bottom-most area by pressing then dragging upwards. And I believe that OS related functionality to be the reason.

The touch event probably do not reach the app properly over these areas. I am seeking to be able to have controllers placed here and have them work just as they are in other places.

[image]

This was done by adding a `VBox` layout, with `TextField` and `TextArea` to Gluon `Layer` - and then adding it to Layers of a class extending Gluon `View` (Called "BasicView").

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean you want to get access to the native iOS areas (menus) and be able to modify its content?

Comment: I mean literally. Controllers being put on the same areas as the ones mentioned stops to work. They become almost impossible to select. I think the touch event never reaches the app (and then to the controller).

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. A JavaFX app on iOS takes the whole screen (but the status bar). When you press and drag from top, you get the iOS search and notifications area, and from bottom the iOS quick settings menu. If you place JavaFX controls at any position, those should work. Can you add a screenshot of what is failing for you?

Comment: I have a textfield on top/behind (same x, y position) as the status bar. It can be selected but it is very hard. double tap works some time (50 % of the times), and touching once works in around 25 % of the times. I have a textarea in the middle (outputting the type of events being done on the textfield).

Comment: It is beacuse the status bar cover most of the textfield then? So that the touchable part of the textfield becomes so small.

Comment: I wouldn't place any control under the status bar. Make sure you have some padding on top. Using Gluon Mobile this is taken care of internally.

Comment: See this [sample](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.3.7/#_creating_a_layer) of a custom layer, you'll need to set its size and location, and that should fix the issue. Or you can use a built-in layer like `SidePopupView`.

Comment: I have another solution I will try - Beacuse I would like to use a special kind of menusystem that I am making myself. Thank you for the info and for those suggestions.